# What permissions are needed to ftp to Centos server

Tags: linux, centos

What permissions are needed to ftp to Centos server?

Answer (score 1):

This depends completely on the configuration of the ftp daemon running on your server.

You could configure an anonymous login to a common directory or let only *real* users log into their accounts.

Check your ftp daemon documentation.

```
rpm -qa | grep -i ftp
```